# Python pass arguments to callable function reference

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am not sure if I worded the question the best way but, in Django, our model fields can have a default value, which can be a function

Example : *(Yes I know it is pointless in context, and I know I can extend the base class/overwrite the save method)*

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    #How do i pass an argument without calling it
    model_name = models.IntegerField(default=my_func)


def my_func(model):
    return model.__name__
```

This should result in an error as my_func expects the model parameter, but I can't call it in the default because it expects a function reference and will call it later.

Can this be done in Python?

**Edit:** After some more research I came up with this using lambda, not sure if the logic is correct, it looks like magic to me

```
def auto_field(model):
    last_id = model.objects.latest('cod')
    if last_id is not None:
        return last_id + 1
    return 1

class MyModel(models.Model):
    uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    cod = models.IntegerField(default=lambda: auto_field(self), editable=False, unique=True)
```

*By the way, Django's AutoField has a limitation that it has to be the primary-key*

Comment: Callables don't accept any parameters. If you could explain what you are really trying to do, maybe we can suggest a workaround.

Comment: @CésarGarcíaTapia auto incrementing non primary field, I edited a exampled that I came up with, not sure the logic is correct though

Comment: Nope, you can't use lambdas as callables, because they cannot be serialized by Migrations. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default

Comment: @CésarGarcíaTapia well that's a bummer, I'm guessing overwriting each model's save method is the only way then?

Comment: If you override the save method you should do it in a super class to inherit from since you want to use this in multiple models

Comment: @yummies So, something like `models.Model.save = 'insert function here'` ?

Comment: No, look up python inheritance. A comment isn't the best place to explain it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can inherit from AutoField and avoid the call to `_check_primary_key` by overriding the `check` method.

```
class MyAutoField(models.AutoField):
    def check(self, **kwargs):
        errors = models.Field.check(**kwargs)
        # errors.extend(self._check_primary_key())
        return errors

class MyModel(models.Model):
    uid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    cod = MyAutoField(editable=False, unique=True)
```

Comment: This has to be the most elegant solution

Comment: SQL databases generally don't allow you to use multiple auto increment fields, hence the django restriction

Comment: @yuumies It shouldn't be a problem with an uuid since that's calculated in python, also the restriction shouldn't exist if you already defined a primary_key, and have only one auto_field

Comment: There's a problem with this, even if I set primary_key = false in the arguments, it still is trying to create as a primary_key in the database, something is overwriting it

Comment: Yes, it is the `def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super(AutoField, self).deconstruct()
        del kwargs['blank']
        kwargs['primary_key'] = True
        return name, path, args, kwargs`

Comment: Perhaps you'd override it too, but I'm not aware about the validity of the @yummies ' comment.

Comment: Some common ones [MySQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.5-en/create-table.html) see auto_increment, [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html), [MSSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd338603.aspx), [Maria](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/auto_increment/). I think you can do it on postgresql, although I believe you'd have to manually write the query